# Flutter Flame SpawnComponent sample

Tags: flutter, flame

Trying to implement the Flame SpawnComponent but get the error:

The argument type 'MyComponent Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PositionComponent Function(int)'.dartargument_type_not_assignable

Here is my code which is basically from the documentation.  Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

```
SpawnComponent(
// Error on next line
  factory: () => MyComponent(size: Vector2(10, 20), amount: 2),
  period: 0.5,
  area: Circle(Vector2(100, 200), 150),
);

class MyComponent extends PositionComponent with HasVisibility {
  MyComponent({required Vector2 size, required int amount});

  @override
  void renderTree(Canvas canvas) {
    // Check for visibility
    if (isVisible) {
      // Custom code here

      // Continue rendering the tree
      super.renderTree(canvas);
    }
  }
}
```

I expect a Component that spawns PositionComponents at the given interval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument for the factory seems to be missing from the documentation, this is what it should look like:

```dart
SpawnComponent(
  factory: (int x) => MyComponent(size: Vector2(10, 20), amount: 2),
  period: 0.5,
  area: Circle(Vector2(100, 200), 150),
);
```

Where x is the number of components that the `SpawnComponent` has spawned so far.

On another note, you don't need to override `renderTree` to toggle the visibility when you are using the `HasVisibility` mixin, that mixin already handles it for you.

Comment: Works great now. Thanks

Comment: @PhilCiraolo good to hear! Please press the checkmark underneath the voting arrows to mark the answer as accepted so that others can learn from it.